# How to install a new package

Tags: packages, texstudio

Please, do not mark this question as duplicate: I am aware that some other users already have asked how to install a package, but honestly, the answers did not help me...

I am relatively new to all this, i.e. I know how to use the latex "language", which I used (even though it was Mathjax) when writing in Math-Stackexchange. Notwithstanding, I do not know how to program more complex things...

Recently, I was trying to install a package you can fin [here](http://amj-math.com/submissions/). The editor I use, Texstudio, did not recognize the package and claimed "We could not startBuild & View:PdfLaTeX:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "arhimede".tex." which, as you might guess, I do not understand.

I use a Mac and would like to know how to manually download the package *arhimede*, in order Texstudio to recognize it.

I read elsewhere in Tex.stackexchange, that the packages do not depend on the editor, but on the package-manager. If so, what's a package manager, how does it work and where can I get one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYJkU17Wfnc

Comment: Dear @jsbibra, thanks for the video! I have just installed MiKTeX but had a problem. First of all, the program is not identic to the one shown in the video (it might be because of using Mac instead of Windows). Anyhow, the thing is, that whenever I try to upload the .sty-archieve MiKTeX does not ask me to confirm... and when I check the library later, the package has not been uploaded. I also wanted to ask how to connect MiKTeX and TexStudio, since I downloaded MiKTeX after Texstudio...

Comment: there is no upload required -- for the installation go step by step -- install miktex then studio for correct path recognition -- problems can be resolved here but if we go step by step